# Gratis self-hosted time-tracking web service for teams

Tags: gratis, time-management, web-services

Recently a court in Germany decided that employers need to track their employees working time. However, several companies who have a remote-working setup don't do that - they just trust their employees.

Is there a [web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service) that can...

1. Let users login using GSuite
2. Let users basically click on a button "I'm working"
3. Let users manually edit the 5 working days
4. Give a summary of the working hours of the current week / the past month
5. Notify if the past weeks hours don't match the expected hours.

A paid (non-self hosted) service would also be fine. If it integrates with Personio / Google calendar it would be a bonus.

Preferred would a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) self-hosted web service.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Kimai](https://github.com/kevinpapst/kimai2) for this, even though it may not meet all requirements.

- It is multi-user, open-source, and can be self-hosted. However, there is also a paid cloud version.
- G Suite: there is something in the issues queue for this. You can approach/sponsor the developers to do it. I can't recall if now done.
- It has an easy screen to enter all weekly work in one go. Hence can be used for "5 working days" entry.
- It has reports for summary of working hours per week/month/year etc.
- It has a timer for those that want to time tasks/acvtivities. May be this is what you mean by 'click on a button "I'm working"'?
- With regards to Notifications, you can ask developers about this.

I use a self-hosted version.